Docker Add Proxy to config.json
I am new to Docker. So running into a host of problem. So I wanted to add a proxy to my config.json file. Because docker pull is currently giving me TLS Handshake Timeout error. One of my colleagues suggested adding a proxy, because I am behind a corporate network.
But when I try to add a proxy using this guide:
https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/#options
I realise that the config.json is in the root directory and I have no way of accessing it or editing it.
So i thought of changing the .docker path to some place where I can edit it freely. But the command:
sudo docker --config /home/sam2004/.docker/ is also throwing an error.
Something like:
Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND

A self-sufficient runtime for containers

.
.
.

And a host of commands lists after that.
I am a bit stuck here. So any help would be appreciated.

i would simple switch to podman  (daemonless)
you can try to create a user config : ~/.docker/config.json
or you can pass it as arg or set it in env
CLI
docker run --env HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.example.com:3128" redis

ENV   not recomendet
root@k8master:~/runner# export http_proxy="http://192.168.10.208:3128"
root@k8master:~/runner# docker pull gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
latest: Pulling from gitlab/gitlab-runner 

proxy for docker daemon
